# Why is “umwehten” used instead of “umwehte” in this Kafka text?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

Below is a quote from Kafkas *Die Verwandlung* (boldface mine).

> Er fühlte ein leichtes Jucken oben auf dem Bauch; schob sich auf dem Rücken langsam näher zum Bettpfosten, um den Kopf besser heben zu können; fand die juckende Stelle, die mit lauter kleinen weißen Pünktchen besetzt war, die er nicht zu beurteilen verstand; und wollte mit einem Bein die Stelle betasten, zog es aber gleich zurück, denn bei der Berührung **umwehten** ihn Kälteschauer.

I notice that in many translations into English, the word *Kälteschauer* was translated as *a cold shower* or *a cold shudder,* which is singular. So, why is *umwehten* used instead of *umwehte?*

Comment: Weil die Übersetzer Kafka übersetzten, nicht umgekehrt. So why used 'a shudder' and not 'shudders'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While some English translations may render it as singular, *Kälteschauer* is plural in the German text. This is indicated not only by the verb form, but also the absence of an article: The singular would be *… umwehte ihn **ein** Kälteschauer*.

It is not uncommon for languages to differ in their use of singular and plural. A famous example is that you have to say

> They shook their heads.

in English, whereas in German you have a choice:

> Sie schüttelten den Kopf.
>   Sie schüttelten die Köpfe.

The idea is here that each person is only shaking one head (their own); but of course the whole group possessed multiple heads.

Comment: "It is not uncommon for languages to differ in their use of singular and plural." - I think this particular case has nothing to do with that phenomenon. More likely, the primary issue at hand is that the singular and plural forms of *Kälteschauer* are the same, so when searching for *Kälteschauer* in a dictionary without the context from the sentence, there will be no indication the OP was looking at the plural form instead of the (default) singular form.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I was thinking of the professional translators who did the published translations. Can you believe they didn’t understand the grammar? I think it is more likely they recognized _Kälteschauer_ as plural in this sentence, but consciously translated it to _a cold shower_ or _a cold shudder_ in singular because it was more natural English in their opinion.

Comment: Granted, I understand the OP's "in many translations into English" as the OP's way of saying what dictionaries say the isolated word *Kälteschauer* means. If they are indeed referring to complete translations of the text in question, you have a point.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I checked some published translations, and they indeed mostly use singular; one each has plural or avoids the noun: _he was overcome by a cold shudder_ (David Wyllie), _the contact made a cold shiver run through him_ (Willa Muir/Edwin Muir), _the touch caused him to shudder involuntarily_ (Michael Hofmann), _he was swept by cold shivers_ (Joyce Crick), _the contact felt like a cold shower all over him_ (Ian Johnston), _the contact sent a cold shiver through him_ (Stanley Corngold), _he felt a cold shiver whenever he touched it_ (John R. Williams).

Comment: Warum die Übersetzer den Singular bevorzugt haben kann schlecht ermittelt werden und muss unerheblich sein, weil Kafka seinen Text ja vor diesen geschrieben hat. Die Frage ist, wieso man von der Übersetzung ausgeht um das Original zu hinzufragen - ob man da nicht alle 2 Sätze in Fraglichkeiten hineinstolpert.